How to download a zip file attachment from an Oracle UCM SOAP response in Microsoft Power Automate
I'm attempting to access an Oracle UCM folder using Microsoft Power Automate, that has Zip files in it. A CSV file is included with every Zip file. The objective is to copy this Zip file (or extract the CSV file) to a SharePoint site.
Problem: The SOAP response for the Zip file is Base64 encoded, and when converting this to Binary the output contains Metadata of the Zip file and headers before the actual content of the Zip file (where it starts with PK)
SOAP response:
"$content-type": "application/octet-stream"
"$content": "LS0tLS0tPV......."
}

$content Base64 when converted to Binary:
content-type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
content-transfer-encoding: 8bit
content-id: <.....>

------=_part_
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content_id: <....>

PK.......... 

------=_part_

My understanding is, this part starting from PK is the actual Zip file content
To remove the header and metadata, I converted the output to string in Power Automate and used Substring to remove everything before PK. But when I convert it to String, the content gets corrupted and not able to open the Zip file (I opened the file in text Notepad++ to see the outputs mostly are '?')
How to extract the Zip content alone without converting the output to string? Power Automate is the only available option I have.
What I have tried till now:

SAOP Response using HTTP action --> Base64toBinary --> BinarytoString --> Substring to remove everything before PK --> StringtoBinary --> Create file in SharePoint

In this step, the output Zip file is inaccessible.

SAOP Response --> Base64toBinary --> Substring to remove everything before PK --> Create file in SharePoint

Substring can only accept string, here the Binary output is an Object, the step failed.
For testing purpose, I saved the file directly after the Base64toBinary step, open the file in Notepad++, removed everything before PK and saved the file. When I do this I was able to open/extract the Zip file without any issue.
